# Try Catch Block seems to be Ignored under IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, try-catch

I have a aspx page with several methods calls in the `page_load` event, some of them
are from referenced .DLL (BusinessLayer) but all of it is wrapped in try/catch within
(if !this.IsPostBack) conditional block. in the `catch` part I have a method call which outputs some javascript to show error message in fancybox jquery plugin because this
much better error notification then implementing error pages with redirects.

While running this in VS 10 all works fine, error occurs and fancybox pops up but
when I moved it to IIS 7 it shows standard asp.net error page with ugly message. I am lost. Here is what I do on page_load:

```
       try
        {
            SetDataSource();
            IBusinessLayer bl=this.GetInstanceOf(IBusinessLayer); 
            this.LabelStatus.Text=bl.GetStatus();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.ShowError(ex);
        }
```

however catch block never fires.

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: First you need to locate the real error. Can you see the Event Viewer, or run it from local host to get full error details ? With out error details you do not know where the error is. Maybe a second error happends on ShowError. For sure iis 7 not ignore try catch. :)

Comment: Seems like the error is happening somewhere else and it is actually throwing the error there, instead of passing it to the calling method.

Comment: for instance the error which I throw based on some condition in bl.GetStatus() using : throw new Exception("Business error"), will be shown as  as default asp.net error with my text "Business error"  disregarding catch. I am starting to think something is wrong with .NET/IIS setup/config on server

Comment: I think the first thing you should do is spend some time learning how to read the "error page with ugly message".   As a developer it is *crucial* you understand exactly what that page is telling you; and it is usually extremely informative as to where the problem is.  Also, when asking for help on SO it is usually a good idea to post at least part of that error message.  Specifically the stack trace.  In your case it's entirely possible there is an additional error inside of your ShowError() method.

Comment: I have the same error. Has anyone known the fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I guarantee this has nothing to do with IIS7 ignoring your `try catch` block. However, it is not uncommon to see applications behave differently when ran from outside the debugger, after all, its running in a completely different environment.

Try attaching the debugger to your `w3wp.exe` process running your website and step through it to see where the real error is.

This link provides an example of how to attach to process from Visual Studio 2010:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx

To prove simply that IIS isn't ignoring your try catch just make a simple proof of concept page that just does this on Page_Load():

```
public void Page_Load()
{
    try 
    {
        throw new Exception("Test try-catch block");
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        lblException.Text = e.Message;
    }
}
```